# jQuery - How to add to list element dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

This may have been asked a lot in SO but I'm unable to make it work.
As the title says I need to append `<ul> <li>` dynamically inside one  element.
The method `addUsers()` is called everytime there is an update to json.

**Html:**

```
<div id="users"></div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
function addUsers() {
    var users = $('#users'); // div element
    users.html(''); // clears the div everytime it come inside addUsers() method
    users.append('<ul>');
    for (var i = 0; i < json.users.length; i++) {       
        users.append('<li><a href="#"><span class="user-list">'+json.users[i]+'</span></a></li>');
    }
}
```

**Excepted Output:**

```
<div id="users">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="user-list">User1</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="user-list">User2</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="user-list">User3</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

**Actual Output:**

```
<div id="users">
    <ul></ul> //UL is ending here
        <li><a href="#"><span class="user-list">User1</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="user-list">User2</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="user-list">User3</span></a></li>
</div>
```

I must be doing something wrong. Appreciate any pointers. Thanks!

Comment: You're appending everything to users, whereas what you want to do is append the `li` elements to the `ul`, like Rajaprabhu Aravindasamy says.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are actually appending the `li` elements to the `Div` element. But in your context `ul` is present inside of that `Div` element. So you have to use `.find()` function to select that.

Try,

```
var xUl = users.find('ul');

for (var i = 0; i < json.users.length; i++) {       
        xUl.append('<li><a href="#"><span class="user-list">'+json.users[i]+'</span></a></li>');
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function addUsers() {
    var users  = $('#users').empty(),
        ul     = $('<ul />');

    $.each(json.users, function(_, user) {
        var li = $('<li />'),
            a  = $('<a />',  {href : '#'}),
            sp = $('<span />', {'class' : 'user-list', text : user});

        ul.append( li.append( a.append(sp) ) );
    });
    users.append(ul);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var temp = $('<ul> </ul>');
//LOOP
temp.append('<li><a href="#"><span class="user-list">'+json.users[i]+'</span></a></li>')
//END LOOP
users.html(temp)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not able to format my code snippet in comment section so adding it in Answer.
First of all thanks @Rajaprabhu @adeneo and others for such quick rsponse.

Here is the modified code. Please let me know if that is correct.

```
var users = $('#users'); // div element
    users.html(''); // clears the div everytime it come inside addUsers() method
    users.append('<ul>');
    var xUl = users.find('ul');
    for (var i = 0; i < json.users.length; i++) {       
         xUl.append('<li><a href="#"><span class="user-list">'+json.users[i]+'</span></a></li>');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(function () {

    var i = 0;
    var users_div = $('#users');
        users_div.html('');
        var child_ul = $('<ul></ul>').appendTo(users_div);

        for (i; i < 3; i += 1) {
            var child_li = $('<li></li>').appendTo(child_ul);
            var child_a = $('<a></a>').attr({
                href: '#'
            }).appendTo(child_li);
            var child_span = $('<span></span>').attr({
                class: 'userlist'
            });
            child_span.appendTo(child_a);
        }
    })();
```